# How to create google compute instance template with container image

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform

I'm trying to create google_compute_instance_template with image container.

On the GUI under instance template you've to check the checkbox:
"Deploy a container image to this VM instance"

After that, I can add the container image URI and on the advanced options, I can add environment params, args, etc ...

Unfortunately, I didn't find how to do it from Terraform.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this terraform module is what you're looking for - https://github.com/terraform-google-modules/terraform-google-container-vm

example usage:

```
module "gce-container" {
  source = "github.com/terraform-google-modules/terraform-google-container-vm"
  version = "0.1.0"

  container = {
    image="gcr.io/google-samples/hello-app:1.0"
    env = [
      {
        name = "TEST_VAR"
        value = "Hello World!"
      }
    ],
    volumeMounts = [
      {
        mountPath = "/cache"
        name      = "tempfs-0"
        readOnly  = "false"
      },
      {
        mountPath = "/persistent-data"
        name      = "data-disk-0"
        readOnly  = "false"
      },
    ]
  }

  volumes = [
    {
      name = "tempfs-0"

      emptyDir = {
        medium = "Memory"
      }
    },
    {
      name = "data-disk-0"

      gcePersistentDisk = {
        pdName = "data-disk-0"
        fsType = "ext4"
      }
    },
  ]

  restart_policy = "Always"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The Managed Instance example in https://github.com/terraform-google-modules/terraform-google-container-vm has not been updated for Terraform version 1.1.2 which is what i am using so i'm going to post my configuration.

```
module "gce-container" {
  source = "terraform-google-modules/container-vm/google"
  version = "~> 2.0"

  container = {
    image="gcr.io/project-name/image-name:tag"
    securityContext = {
      privileged : true
    }
    tty : true
    env = [
      {
        name = "PORT"
        value = "3000"
      }
    ],

    # Declare volumes to be mounted.
    # This is similar to how docker volumes are declared.
    volumeMounts = []
  }

  # Declare the Volumes which will be used for mounting.
  volumes = []

  restart_policy = "Always"
}
```

```
data "google_compute_image" "gce_container_vm_image" {
  family  = "cos-stable"
  project = "cos-cloud"
}
```

```
resource "google_compute_instance_template" "my_instance_template" {
  name        = "instance-template"
  description = "This template is used to create app server instances"

  // the `gce-container-declaration` key is very important
  metadata = {
    "gce-container-declaration" = module.gce-container.metadata_value
  }
  labels = {
    "container-vm" = module.gce-container.vm_container_label
  }

  machine_type         = "e2-small"
  can_ip_forward       = false

  scheduling {
    automatic_restart   = true
    on_host_maintenance = "MIGRATE"
  }

  // Create a new boot disk from an image
  disk {
    source_image      = data.google_compute_image.gce_container_vm_image.self_link
    auto_delete       = true
    boot              = true
    disk_type         = "pd-balanced"
    disk_size_gb      = 10
  }

  network_interface {
    subnetwork = google_compute_subnetwork.my-network-subnet.name
    // Add an ephemeral external IP.
    access_config {
      // Ephemeral IP
    }
  }

  service_account {
    # Compute Engine default service account
    email  = "577646309382-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com"
    scopes = ["cloud-platform"]
  }
}
```